# Is it ok to have NaN while comparing fields in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am comparing two integer values, but there is chance of `parseInt` giving NaN. I would like to know if I need to do any additional checks.

```
var txtFromCustomerId = document.getElementById(FROMCUSTOMERID_FIELDNAME);
var txtToCustomerId = document.getElementById(TOCUSTOMERID_FIELDNAME);

if (txtFromCustomerId  != null && txtToCustomerId != null) {
    var fromCustomerId = parseInt(txtFromCustomerId.value);
    var toCustomerId = parseInt(txtToCustomerId.value);

    if (fromCustomerId > toCustomerId) { <---There is chance of parseInt giving Nan
        //some other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: If this data comes from the user typing it in, it seems to me that you ought to check the data the user typed in before you get to this function and not even call this if the values aren't what you are expecting (inform the user that the data is not correct).  So, in answer to your question, you should already know that they are valid numbers before you get here and thus shouldn't have to test for NaN here.

Comment: Actually, I am having these as independent functions that are called by ASP.NET custom validators. So, would it be nice to check for integer types in fromCustomerId and toCustomerId  before comparing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An opinion question,

ideally you should not compare with `NaN`, it always gives `false`.

If that is okay for the code within the comparison, then go ahead, otherwise make sure you are dealing with a proper customer id.

Comment: Yes, it is giving false for the NaN comparisions as per the expectations. But I would like to know if it is ethical to do this way, by knowing that we shouldn't compare if it is not valid values. Does it give wrong outlook overall.

Comment: Question again is, what is inside the `if` block, does it matter ?

Comment: It returns false if the check fails. And if it is NaN, it does nothing which is fine.

Comment: Then, I would not worry, and put a comment `//Dont worry about NaN`

Answer (score 2):

- A blank string **is not** equal to `null`, therefore it can get through.
- `parseInt('')` returns a `NaN`.
- Always use `parseInt()` with the radix (the second parameter). In some implementations, it doesn't default to base 10 (decimal).
- As much as possible, use string comparison (`===`, `!==`, etc). It's best practice.

---

Instead, check for a blank string. Then instead of `parseInt`, you can do a `+`.

```
var text = *get value*
if(text !== ''){
  var number = +text;
}
```